# Enumerate solutions in Gurobi

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I have a LP problem without any objective i.e. it looks like Ax <= B. Now the feasible set contains potentially infinitely many solutions. Is there any way to enumerate different solutions, which are reasonably different among each other?

For now, I am using this code which chooses a random optimization function, hoping that would produce different solutions.

```
import gurobipy as gp
import numpy as np


def solve(A, B):
    model = gp.Model()
    model.Params.OutputFlag = False
    x = model.addVars(A.shape[1]).values()
    for a, b in zip(A, B):
        expr = gp.LinExpr(b)
        expr.addTerms(a, x)
        model.addConstr(expr <= 0)

    expr = gp.LinExpr()
    for x_ in x:
        if np.random.random() < 0.5:
            expr.add(x_)
        else:
            expr.add(-x_)

    model.setObjective(expr, gp.GRB.MAXIMIZE)

    model.optimize()

    return np.array([x_.x for x_ in x])


n_constr = 6
n_var = 5

A = np.random.random((n_constr, n_var)) * 2 - 1
B = np.random.random((n_constr,)) * 2 - 1

for i in range(3):
    print(solve(A, B))
```

One sample output

```
[ 1.59465412  0.          0.         -0.77579453  0.        ]
[-1.42381457  0.          0.         -7.70035252 -8.55823707]
[1.8797086  0.         0.         7.24494007 4.43847791]
```

Is there any elegant Gurobi specific solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is of course a perfectly valid method to sample different solutions. One other possible way is to enumerate all basic feasible solutions (corner points). Not so easy however. There is an interesting trick for this: use binary variables to encode the basis (0=non-basic,1=basic) and then use the Gurobi solution pool to enumerate all feasible integer solutions. That will give you all basic feasible solutions. See [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you mean by reasonably different. Erwin's suggested approach works well if you want solutions at a gap of 1. If you want solutions with a gap of 0.5, define a dummy variable `Z = 2X` and set Z as an integer and X as continuous. You can then use the solution pool in Gurobi to enumerate any number of solutions (specified using `PoolSolutions` parameter [Link](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/examples/poolsearch_py.html#subsubsection:poolsearch.py). Similarly, you can vary the factor k in `Z = k X` to get solutions at some gap. You don't necessarily have to set any objective when using a solution pool. In that case, do not define the `PoolGap`parameter.